# Geometry errors when importing data from ESRI file geodatabase to PostGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, geoserver, ogr, file-geodatabase

When I run the following command to import by data from an ESRI fgdb to postgis...

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -a_srs "EPSG:28355" -t_srs "EPSG:3857" PG:"dbname=tp_test user=postgres port=54321 password=xxxxxxx host=localhost" -overwrite P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\QueryLayer\TP_Query_Final_28355.gdb
```

...I get...!

> Warning 1: organizePolygons() received an unexpected geometry. Either
>   a polygon with interior rings, or a polygon with less than 4 points,
>   or a non-Polygon geometry.  Return arguments as a collection. Warning
>   1: Geometry of polygon cannot be translated to Simple Geometry. All
>   poly gons will be contained in a multipolygon.

I have checked geometry in ESRI and it reports no errors. I am running multipart to singlepart to see if this resolves the issues but this is crashing arcmap 10.1 as is dissolve. It ran a sort without issues and you can open the dataset.

I successfully imported the dataset earlier but then had to run the [ESRI Dice tool](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/07/23/dicing-godzillas-features-with-too-many-vertices/) to split the large polygons to no more than 15,000 vertices so that it processes faster. 
[image]

I am new to postgis.

**Is there a way to correct the issues in the new gdb or to split the polygons in postgis itself?**

Answer (score 2):

If your data is already in PostGIS, try running:

```
select * from table where ST_NPoints(the_geom) < 4
```

This will return all rows that cause the warning, that is, it will help you track down data errors in PostGIS.

Comment: I only have the dataset in postgis from BEFORE running Dice. If I am going to use the existing postgis dataset I need a tool similar to Dice to split each polygon to <15,000 vertices.

Comment: you could try if error is coming from that data by runnis isValid() and ST_NPoints() to data